# Opening Your Command Prompt In A Text Editor - What Is This Called?

Tags: bash, shell, line-editor

One of my favorite tricks in Bash is when I open my command prompt in a text editor. I do this (in vi mode) by pressing `ESC v`. When I do this, whatever is in my command prompt is now displayed in my $EDITOR of choice. I can then edit the command as if it were a document, and when I save and exit everything in that temp file is executed.

I'm surprised that none of my friends have heard of this tip, so I've been looking for docs I can share. The problem is that I haven't been able to find *anything* on it. Also, the search terms related to this tip are very common, so that doesn't help when Googling for the docs.

Does anyone know what this technique is called so I can actually look it up?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In `bind -p` listing, I can see the command is called `edit-and-execute-command`, and is bound to <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd> in the emacs mode.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks. Also, thanks for showing me how to look something like this up in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This action of "escaping" from the editor into a temporary shell is often referred to as "shell out"

Example: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/gs/node5.html